# Is there anything like HashTab for Linux?

Tags: linux, checksum

I've recently installed Linux, and I know that you can use "md5sum filename" in terminal, but on Windows there is an AMAZING software called [HashTab](http://beeblebrox.org/) that incorporates it into the shell.

Its awesome, you just right click a file, it gives you the md5, crc32, and sha-1, and it provides a box where you can copy the actual md5 and it compares it for you.  I think this program is ingenious, and I hope there is an alternative for linux.  Does anyone know of one?

Comment: Which desktop environment (or really, which file manager) are you using?

Comment: Gnome and nautilus

Comment: +1 for explaining what it does, and not assuming everybody will know it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a former Windows XP user I got used to the Hashtab-tool in the Windows Explorer properties window. In search of an Ubuntu GNU Linux equivalent of this handy Hastab-tool I recently stumbled across a great hastab tool called **"GtkHash"** for Ubuntu GNU Linux (just search for "GtkHash" in the "Ubuntu Software Center").

Installation of "GtkHash" in Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick Meerkat takes only a few seconds and afterwards the tool can be found under:

- Applications

  - Accessories

    - GtkHash

**GtkHash** supports hash functions like:

- MD5
- SHA1
- SHA256
- SHA512
- RIPEMD
- HAVAL
- TIGER
- WHIRLPOOL
- and others.

I personally find "GtkHash" to be the best substitute for the hashtab-tool experience I had back in my Windows XP days for Ubuntu GNU Linux.

Greetings to all linux users worldwide! :)

Comment: thanks, supercheetah's answer was the best solution, but this is much simpler

Answer (score 7):

This is the next best thing, I think.  Put the following code into `$HOME/.gnome2/nautilus-scripts`:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Released into the public domain.
#
for arg
do

md5=$(md5sum "$arg" | awk '{print $1}')
sha1=$(sha1sum "$arg" | awk '{print $1}')
crc32=$(crc32 "$arg")

  gdialog --title "Hashes" --msgbox "File $arg\nmd5   $md5\nsha1  $sha1\ncrc32 $crc32" 800 1100

done
```

I called the file `hashes`, but you can call it whatever you want.  Make sure to set the execute permission (e.g. `chmod +x hashes`).

Here's the second part I promised:

```
#!/bin/sh
# Released into the public domain.
#
for arg
do

md5=$(md5sum "$arg" | awk '{print $1}')
md5compare=$(gdialog --title "MD5 comparison" --inputbox "MD5 hash to compare:" 200 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3)

if [ "$md5compare" = "$md5" ]; then
    gdialog --title "Match" --msgbox "Match confirmed" 200 200
else
    gdialog --title "No match" --msgbox "No match" 200 200
fi

done
```

This second script I called `compare hashes`.

EDIT: This is the final version.  This one does both the hashes, and comparison with a `while` loop so that more than one comparison can be done.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Released into the public domain.
#
for arg
do
    md5=$(md5sum "$arg" | awk '{print $1}')
    sha1=$(sha1sum "$arg" | awk '{print $1}')
    crc32=$(crc32 "$arg")
    compare_msg="MD5 hash to compare:"
    md5compare=$(gdialog --title "Hashes and MD5 comparison" --inputbox "File $arg\nmd5\t\t$md5\nsha1\t\t$sha1\ncrc32\t$crc32\n\n$compare_msg" 1100 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 )
    while [ $? -eq 0 ]
    do
        if [ "$md5compare" = "$md5" ]; then
            compare_msg="Match confirmed"
        else
            compare_msg="No match\n\t\t$md5compare"
        fi
        md5compare=$(gdialog --title "Hashes and MD5 comparison" --inputbox "File $arg\nmd5\t\t$md5\nsha1\t\t$sha1\ncrc32\t$crc32\n\n$compare_msg" 1100 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 )
    done
done
```

This final version I called `hash and compare`.

EDIT: I just added some formatting niceties.

EDIT: I figured out how to avoid using a temporary file.

Comment: Oh, I guess you also wanted it to compare stuff.  Shouldn't be too hard to extend the script, but I'll have to do that later.

Comment: I just realized that I think I could combine the two into one script.  I'll do that in a bit.

Comment: You're awesome!  My only complaint is the interface is very primitive, but you made it work :-)

Comment: It would probably look better with zenity, but that's not always installed, and I know that gdialog is available anywhere gnome is installed.

Answer (score 3):

I've always liked the handy, script-able md5sum command.
However, there appears to be a Java version called [**JSummer**](http://zero-sys.net/portal/index.php?kat=70) at **Sourceforge**.
Maybe, it will work for you.